# Creating a table, dropping it and referencing the results

Tags: sql

I'm creating a table using multiple subselects. So I am getting data from multiple places within one SQL Database.

What I want is to 1. Set the above as a table itself and 2. create a new table using the above results.

So I will call the above [table1].

I just want to know how to set this as a (temporary) table so i can then start to add new script which I can use to the data I have now received in my new table to display.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Do you really need that mess of nested subselects, instead of simple joins?

Comment: This is one part of about 100 with 1000 tables in total.

Comment: That doesn't answer any of our questions, but OK.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for **SELECT INTO** clause:

```
Select (select Project.Number from Project where Project.ProjectID = PurchaseOrder.ProjectID) as [Project],
       PurchaseOrder.Number,
       (Select GoodsReceipt.ReceiptNumber from GoodReceipt where GoodsReceipt.ReferenceID = PurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderID) as [GReceipt]
INTO TABLE1
From PurchaseOrder
```

Comment: _Might_ is key here as we don't know the database.

Comment: Now in the same script how do I start creating my new table and pulling in my new data from [table1]

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : I agree, but I wrote the answer as for most DBMS this clause is same.

Comment: @AgentShwang: This will create a new table named `TABLE1` for you and then you can query the new table just like you query an ordinary table.

Comment: They want a temporary table. This does not create that.

Comment: @underscore_d : My answer was to the initial version of the question where it was nowhere mentioned that OP wants temp table.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write `SELECT YOURCOLUMNS INTO #TEMP FROM XXXXX`

And then you can start a new script by writing

> **Note:** You new script has to been in the same session when you make use of temp tables

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DBO.TEST --This only works on SQL Server 2016

/* Drop Table */
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Test', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE dbo.Test; 

Create Table dbo.TEST (
COLUMNS DATATYPE NULL 
)

Insert into DBO.TEST
SELECT * FROM #TEMP

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Except he doesnt state how to make a temp table. So no, not really. And the questions was to create a temp table

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu No, my first original post was with how to create a temp table. Like the OP asked for. So no, not even close.